# JavaScript sum with ternary operator

Tags: javascript

Well I consider myself fairly good programmer but JavaScript always amuse me with something new ...

Here are three snippet below -

1. Snippet 1 : I am trying to get inline summation of two values based on some condition using ternary shorthand. This snippet gives me sum as 'X' = 0 for all conditions.
2. Snippet 2: When I split that into two sums, I get proper results.
3. Snippet 3: When I use the snippet 1 with brackets around the two sums I get proper results.

I understand why snippet 2 and 3 works but I don't get why snippet 1 doesn't. Can anyone explain that to me? Please.

```js
 let w = 50;
  
  // Snippet 1
  for(let i=0;i<4;i++){   
    let x = w*2*i + (i<2)?w*0:w*2;
    console.log("\t",i,x); 
  }

  // Snippet 2
 for(let i=0;i<4;i++){  
    let x1 = w*2*i;
    let x2 = (i<2)?w*0:w*2;
    let x = x1+x2;
    console.log("\t",i,x); 
  }

  // Snippet 3
  for(let i=0;i<4;i++){   
    let x = (w*2*i) + ((i<2)?w*0:w*2);
    console.log("\t",i,x); 
  }
```

Comment: first is like `(w*2*i + (i<2))?w*0:w*2` - check [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) - ternary operator has a lower precedence than arithmetic operators like +, -, * etc - by the way, this operator precedence is not unique to javascript - other languages with `?:` behave the same (e.g. C, Java etc)

Comment: Everything in front of the `?` is grouped. You probably meant `(i < 2 ? w * 0 : w * 2);` (as used in snippet 3--the parens around `(i < 2)` are superfluous here).

Comment: @ggorlen I totally missed that. I am stupid. officially. Now I understood why it wasn't working.  Yes I understand operator precedence and ternary operator having a lower precedence than arithmetic  operation but your reasoning makes more sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The conditional operator has lower precedence (4) than addition/concatenation (14), so the line here:

```
let x = w*2*i + (i<2)?w*0:w*2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
let x =  w*2*i + (i<2)  ?w*0:w*2;
let x = (w*2*i + (i<2)) ?w*0:w*2;
```

instead of, as you're expecting:

```
let x = w*2*i +  (i<2)?w*0:w*2;
let x = w*2*i + ((i<2)?w*0:w*2); // incorrect
```

In snippet 2 and 3, your explicit `()` parentheses around the conditional, or the separation of the conditional into a separate variable first, are fixing the problem.